# LabelEncoder: How to keep a dictionary that shows original and converted variable

Tags: python, dictionary, label, categorical-data

When using `LabelEncoder` to encode categorical variables into numerics,

how does one keep a dictionary in which the transformation is tracked?

i.e. a dictionary in which I can see which values became what:

```
{'A':1,'B':2,'C':3}
```

Answer (score 16):

I created a dictionary from `classes_`

```
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
ids = le.fit_transform(labels)
mapping = dict(zip(le.classes_, range(len(le.classes_))))
```

to test:

```
all([mapping[x] for x in le.inverse_transform(ids)] == ids)
```

should return `True`.

This works because `fit_transform` uses `numpy.unique` to simultaneously calculate the label encoding and the `classes_` attribute:

```
def fit_transform(self, y):
    self.classes_, y = np.unique(y, return_inverse=True)
    return y
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in a single line:

```
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
my_encodings = {l: i for (i, l) in enumerate(le.fit(data["target"].classes_))}
```